# Fetching more than 1000 records of data using react lazy loading

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

From api response I am getting more than 1000 records, I try to load them using react lazy loading.

After 10 records are loaded, I get "Loading... " for remaining records....

I am using material UI for my template.

I have import lazy loading package in top of the file

Sample API response

```
  {first: 10, second: "66", third: 45} 
  {first: 22, second: "88", third: 67} 
  {first: 31, second: "99", third: 67} 
  {first: 46, second: "22", third: 23} 
  {first: 58, second: "44", third: 34} 
   ....
```

Code :

```
 import LazyLoad from 'react-lazyload';
 
 const columns = [
  { id: 'first', label: 'first' },
  { id: 'second', label: 'second' },
  { id: 'third', label: 'third' }, 
];
 
 <TableContainer>
     <TableBody>
 
                { props.data.length > 0 &&
                  props.data.map((row, index) => {
                    return (
                    <LazyLoad key={index} placeholder ={<Loading /> } >
                      <TableRow tabIndex={-1} key={index}>
                        {columns.map((column) => {
                          const value = row[column.id];
                          return (
                            <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align}>
                              {value}
                            </TableCell>
                          );
                        })}
                      </TableRow>
                      </LazyLoad>
                    );
                  })}
                  </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
```